# Scale at pivot point in an already scaled node

Tags: javafx, scroll, zooming, pinchzoom, panning

I'm trying to create an application with a zoomable/pannable canvas.

**Features**:

- zoom in/out with mouse wheel at pivot points
- drag nodes around on the canvas with left mouse button
- drag the entire canvas with right mouse button

The zooming at the pivot point works as long as you start the zooming at scale 1. Position the mouse over a grid point and scroll the mouse wheel. The pivot point will remain where you started zooming.

**Problem**:

When you zoom in, then move the mouse to another point and zoom again, then the pivot point is shifted and zooming isn't happening anymore at the initial mouse position.

**Example**:

Here's the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * The canvas which holds all of the nodes of the application.
 */
class PannableCanvas extends Pane {

    Scale scaleTransform;

    public PannableCanvas() {

        setPrefSize(600, 600);
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey; -fx-border-color: blue;");

        // add scale transform
        scaleTransform = new Scale( 1.0, 1.0);
        getTransforms().add( scaleTransform);

        // logging
        addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> { 
            System.out.println( 
                    "canvas event: " + ( ((event.getSceneX() - getBoundsInParent().getMinX()) / getScale()) + ", scale: " + getScale())
                    );
            System.out.println( "canvas bounds: " + getBoundsInParent());   
                });

    }

    /**
     * Add a grid to the canvas, send it to back
     */
    public void addGrid() {

        double w = getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        double h = getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();

        // add grid
        Canvas grid = new Canvas(w, h);

        // don't catch mouse events
        grid.setMouseTransparent(true);

        GraphicsContext gc = grid.getGraphicsContext2D();

        gc.setStroke(Color.GRAY);
        gc.setLineWidth(1);

        // draw grid lines
        double offset = 50;
        for( double i=offset; i < w; i+=offset) {
            // vertical
            gc.strokeLine( i, 0, i, h);
            // horizontal
            gc.strokeLine( 0, i, w, i);
        }

        getChildren().add( grid);

        grid.toBack();
    }

    public Scale getScaleTransform() {
        return scaleTransform;
    }

    public double getScale() {
        return scaleTransform.getY();
    }

    /**
     * Set x/y scale
     * @param scale
     */
    public void setScale( double scale) {
        scaleTransform.setX(scale);
        scaleTransform.setY(scale);
    }

    /**
     * Set x/y pivot points
     * @param x
     * @param y
     */
    public void setPivot( double x, double y) {
        scaleTransform.setPivotX(x);
        scaleTransform.setPivotY(y);
    }
}


/**
 * Mouse drag context used for scene and nodes.
 */
class DragContext {

    double mouseAnchorX;
    double mouseAnchorY;

    double translateAnchorX;
    double translateAnchorY;

}

/**
 * Listeners for making the nodes draggable via left mouse button. Considers if parent is zoomed.
 */
class NodeGestures {

    private DragContext nodeDragContext = new DragContext();

    PannableCanvas canvas;

    public NodeGestures( PannableCanvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;

    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
        return onMousePressedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
        return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // left mouse button => dragging
            if( !event.isPrimaryButtonDown())
                return;

            nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
            nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

            nodeDragContext.translateAnchorX = node.getTranslateX();
            nodeDragContext.translateAnchorY = node.getTranslateY();

        }

    };

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // left mouse button => dragging
            if( !event.isPrimaryButtonDown())
                return;

            double scale = canvas.getScale();

            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

            node.setTranslateX(nodeDragContext.translateAnchorX + (( event.getSceneX() - nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorX) / scale));
            node.setTranslateY(nodeDragContext.translateAnchorY + (( event.getSceneY() - nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorY) / scale));

            event.consume();

        }
    };
}

/**
 * Listeners for making the scene's canvas draggable and zoomable
 */
class SceneGestures {

    private static final double MAX_SCALE = 10.0d;
    private static final double MIN_SCALE = .1d;

    private DragContext sceneDragContext = new DragContext();

    PannableCanvas canvas;

    public SceneGestures( PannableCanvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
        return onMousePressedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
        return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<ScrollEvent> getOnScrollEventHandler() {
        return onScrollEventHandler;
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // right mouse button => panning
            if( !event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
                return;

            sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
            sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

            sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX = canvas.getTranslateX();
            sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY = canvas.getTranslateY();

        }

    };

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // right mouse button => panning
            if( !event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
                return;

            canvas.setTranslateX(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX + event.getSceneX() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX);
            canvas.setTranslateY(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY + event.getSceneY() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY);

            event.consume();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Mouse wheel handler: zoom to pivot point
     */
    private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> onScrollEventHandler = new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {

            double delta = 1;

            double scale = canvas.getScale(); // currently we only use Y, same value is used for X
            double oldScale = scale;

            if (event.getDeltaY() < 0)
                scale -= delta;
            else
                scale += delta;

            if (scale <= MIN_SCALE) {
                scale = MIN_SCALE;
            } else if (scale >= MAX_SCALE) {
                scale = MAX_SCALE;
            }

            // pivot value must be untransformed, i. e. without scaling
            canvas.setPivot( 
                    ((event.getSceneX() - canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()) / oldScale),
                    ((event.getSceneY() - canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()) / oldScale)
                    );

            canvas.setScale( scale);

            System.out.println( "new pivot x: " + canvas.scaleTransform.getPivotX() + "/" + canvas.scaleTransform.getPivotY() + ", new scale: " + scale);
            System.out.println( "bounds: " + canvas.getBoundsInParent());       

            event.consume();

        }

    };


}

/**
 * An application with a zoomable and pannable canvas.
 */
public class ScrollApplication extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Group group = new Group();

        // create canvas
        PannableCanvas canvas = new PannableCanvas();

        // we don't want the canvas on the top/left in this example => just
        // translate it a bit
        canvas.setTranslateX(100);
        canvas.setTranslateY(100);

        // create sample nodes which can be dragged
        NodeGestures nodeGestures = new NodeGestures( canvas);

        Label label1 = new Label("Draggable node 1");
        label1.setTranslateX(10);
        label1.setTranslateY(10);
        label1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Label label2 = new Label("Draggable node 2");
        label2.setTranslateX(100);
        label2.setTranslateY(100);
        label2.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label2.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Label label3 = new Label("Draggable node 3");
        label3.setTranslateX(200);
        label3.setTranslateY(200);
        label3.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label3.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Circle circle1 = new Circle( 300, 300, 50);
        circle1.setStroke(Color.ORANGE);
        circle1.setFill(Color.ORANGE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        circle1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        circle1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100,100);
        rect1.setTranslateX(450);
        rect1.setTranslateY(450);
        rect1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        rect1.setFill(Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        rect1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        rect1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        canvas.getChildren().addAll(label1, label2, label3, circle1, rect1);

        group.getChildren().add(canvas);

        // create scene which can be dragged and zoomed
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 1024, 768);

        SceneGestures sceneGestures = new SceneGestures(canvas);
        scene.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, sceneGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        scene.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, sceneGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());
        scene.addEventFilter( ScrollEvent.ANY, sceneGestures.getOnScrollEventHandler());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        canvas.addGrid();

    }
}
```

It's obviously something wrong with the pivot point calculation, but I can't figure out what it is and how to fix it.

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: See also this [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29530135/230513).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First I would recommend to not scale in linear steps but by factors to smooth the scaling:

```
           double delta = 1.2;
           if (event.getDeltaY() < 0)
                scale /= delta;
            else
                scale *= delta;
```

... and to be somehow bossy, I recommend curly brackets as a good style ;-) :

```
               double delta = 1.2;
               if (event.getDeltaY() < 0) {
                    scale /= delta;
               } else {
                    scale *= delta;
               }
```

... and to use the mouse scroll value for even better quality:

```
               double delta = 1.2;
               if (event.getDeltaY() < 0) {
                    scale /= Math.pow(delta, -event.getDeltaY()/20);
               } else {
                    scale *= Math.pow(delta, event.getDeltaY()/20);
               }
```

... that is finally the same as:

```
               scale *= Math.pow(1.01, event.getDeltaY());
```

Second I recomend to use the canvas translate and scale properties instead of a Transformation:

```
public class ZoomApplication extends Application {
    static public class PannableCanvas extends Pane {

        DoubleProperty myScale = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);

        public PannableCanvas() {

            setPrefSize(600, 600);
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey; -fx-border-color: blue;");

            // add scale transform
            scaleXProperty().bind(myScale);
            scaleYProperty().bind(myScale);

            // logging
            addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> { 
                System.out.println( 
                        "canvas event: " + ( ((event.getSceneX() - getBoundsInParent().getMinX()) / getScale()) + ", scale: " + getScale())
                        );
                System.out.println( "canvas bounds: " + getBoundsInParent());   
            });

        }

        /**
         * Add a grid to the canvas, send it to back
         */
        public void addGrid() {

            double w = getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
            double h = getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();

            // add grid
            Canvas grid = new Canvas(w, h);

            // don't catch mouse events
            grid.setMouseTransparent(true);

            GraphicsContext gc = grid.getGraphicsContext2D();

            gc.setStroke(Color.GRAY);
            gc.setLineWidth(1);

            // draw grid lines
            double offset = 50;
            for( double i=offset; i < w; i+=offset) {
                // vertical
                gc.strokeLine( i, 0, i, h);
                // horizontal
                gc.strokeLine( 0, i, w, i);
            }

            getChildren().add( grid);

            grid.toBack();
        }

        public double getScale() {
            return myScale.get();
        }

        /**
         * Set x/y scale
         * @param myScale
         */
        public void setScale( double scale) {
            myScale.set(scale);
        }

        /**
         * Set x/y pivot points
         * @param x
         * @param y
         */
        public void setPivot( double x, double y) {
            setTranslateX(getTranslateX()-x);
            setTranslateY(getTranslateY()-y);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Mouse drag context used for scene and nodes.
     */
    class DragContext {

        double mouseAnchorX;
        double mouseAnchorY;

        double translateAnchorX;
        double translateAnchorY;

    }

    /**
     * Listeners for making the nodes draggable via left mouse button. Considers if parent is zoomed.
     */
    class NodeGestures {

        private DragContext nodeDragContext = new DragContext();

        PannableCanvas canvas;

        public NodeGestures( PannableCanvas canvas) {
            this.canvas = canvas;

        }

        public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
            return onMousePressedEventHandler;
        }

        public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
            return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
        }

        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                // left mouse button => dragging
                if( !event.isPrimaryButtonDown())
                    return;

                nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
                nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

                Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

                nodeDragContext.translateAnchorX = node.getTranslateX();
                nodeDragContext.translateAnchorY = node.getTranslateY();

            }

        };

        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                // left mouse button => dragging
                if( !event.isPrimaryButtonDown())
                    return;

                double scale = canvas.getScale();

                Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

                node.setTranslateX(nodeDragContext.translateAnchorX + (( event.getSceneX() - nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorX) / scale));
                node.setTranslateY(nodeDragContext.translateAnchorY + (( event.getSceneY() - nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorY) / scale));

                event.consume();

            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Listeners for making the scene's canvas draggable and zoomable
     */
    class SceneGestures {

        private static final double MAX_SCALE = 10.0d;
        private static final double MIN_SCALE = .1d;

        private DragContext sceneDragContext = new DragContext();

        PannableCanvas canvas;

        public SceneGestures( PannableCanvas canvas) {
            this.canvas = canvas;
        }

        public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
            return onMousePressedEventHandler;
        }

        public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
            return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
        }

        public EventHandler<ScrollEvent> getOnScrollEventHandler() {
            return onScrollEventHandler;
        }

        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                // right mouse button => panning
                if( !event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
                    return;

                sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
                sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

                sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX = canvas.getTranslateX();
                sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY = canvas.getTranslateY();

            }

        };

        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                // right mouse button => panning
                if( !event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
                    return;

                canvas.setTranslateX(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX + event.getSceneX() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX);
                canvas.setTranslateY(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY + event.getSceneY() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY);

                event.consume();
            }
        };

        /**
         * Mouse wheel handler: zoom to pivot point
         */
        private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> onScrollEventHandler = new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {


                double scale = canvas.getScale(); // currently we only use Y, same value is used for X
                double oldScale = scale;

                scale *= Math.pow(1.01, event.getDeltaY());

                if (scale <= MIN_SCALE) {
                    scale = MIN_SCALE;
                } else if (scale >= MAX_SCALE) {
                    scale = MAX_SCALE;
                }

                double f = (scale / oldScale)-1;

                double dx = (event.getSceneX() - (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getWidth()/2 + canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()));
                double dy = (event.getSceneY() - (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getHeight()/2 + canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()));


                canvas.setScale( scale);
                canvas.setPivot(f*dx, f*dy);

                event.consume();

            }

        };


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Group group = new Group();

        // create canvas
        PannableCanvas canvas = new PannableCanvas();

        // we don't want the canvas on the top/left in this example => just
        // translate it a bit
        canvas.setTranslateX(100);
        canvas.setTranslateY(100);

        // create sample nodes which can be dragged
        NodeGestures nodeGestures = new NodeGestures( canvas);

        Label label1 = new Label("Draggable node 1");
        label1.setTranslateX(10);
        label1.setTranslateY(10);
        label1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Label label2 = new Label("Draggable node 2");
        label2.setTranslateX(100);
        label2.setTranslateY(100);
        label2.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label2.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Label label3 = new Label("Draggable node 3");
        label3.setTranslateX(200);
        label3.setTranslateY(200);
        label3.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label3.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Circle circle1 = new Circle( 300, 300, 50);
        circle1.setStroke(Color.ORANGE);
        circle1.setFill(Color.ORANGE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        circle1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        circle1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100,100);
        rect1.setTranslateX(450);
        rect1.setTranslateY(450);
        rect1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        rect1.setFill(Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        rect1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        rect1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        canvas.getChildren().addAll(label1, label2, label3, circle1, rect1);

        group.getChildren().add(canvas);

        // create scene which can be dragged and zoomed
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 1024, 768);

        SceneGestures sceneGestures = new SceneGestures(canvas);
        scene.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, sceneGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        scene.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, sceneGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());
        scene.addEventFilter( ScrollEvent.ANY, sceneGestures.getOnScrollEventHandler());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        canvas.addGrid();

    }
}
```

After some thoughts about zoom, I came to the conclusion, that it would be a good idea to

1. Write an independent zoom helper method to ease the zoom function
2. To also support the pinch-to-zoom gesture with the same method

So I wrote the following helper method:

```
/** Allow to zoom/scale any node with pivot at scene (x,y) coordinates.
 * 
 * @param node
 * @param delta
 * @param x
 * @param y
 */
public static void zoom(Node node, double factor, double x, double y) {
    double oldScale = node.getScaleX();
    double scale = oldScale * factor;
    if (scale < 0.05) scale = 0.05;
    if (scale > 50)  scale = 50;
    node.setScaleX(scale);
    node.setScaleY(scale);

    double  f = (scale / oldScale)-1;
    Bounds bounds = node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal());
    double dx = (x - (bounds.getWidth()/2 + bounds.getMinX()));
    double dy = (y - (bounds.getHeight()/2 + bounds.getMinY()));

    node.setTranslateX(node.getTranslateX()-f*dx);
    node.setTranslateY(node.getTranslateY()-f*dy);
}

public static void zoom(Node node, ScrollEvent event) {
    zoom(node, Math.pow(1.01, event.getDeltaY()), event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
}
public static void zoom(Node node, ZoomEvent event) {
    zoom(node, event.getZoomFactor(), event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
}
```

allowing me to register zoom function on any node as easy as:

```
    myView.setOnScroll(event -> GUITools.zoom(myView, event)); // mouse scroll wheel zoom
    myView.setOnZoom(event -> GUITools.zoom(myView, event)); // pinch to zoom
```

and done...

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick solution. It works as expected :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. I'll definitely use that.

Comment: Seems like the delta depends very much on the mouse wheel settings. I have e. g. a very high resolution screen and hence a high mouse wheel scroll value. When I use your code and zoom out, I instantly get a ~100x100 pixel pane. So I guess one has to consider the multiplier with getDeltaX() and getDeltaY() or use a fixed delta.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible... also I would consider not using the plain mouse-wheel (scroll Y) directly, as it already has the semantics of Y movement of the current view (e.g. using two finger swipe to scroll in X,Y directions on a tablet)... Perhaps a base of 1.003 might be better anyhow instead of 1.01 to be more conservative in zoom speed.

Answer (score 0):

I change your SceneGestures class so now working.

```
class SceneGestures {
    private double oldx;
    private double oldy;
    double ttx=0;
    double tty=0;
    private static final double MAX_SCALE = 10.0d;
    private static final double MIN_SCALE = .1d;

    private DragContext sceneDragContext = new DragContext();

    PannableCanvas canvas;

    public SceneGestures( PannableCanvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
        return onMousePressedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
        return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<ScrollEvent> getOnScrollEventHandler() {
        return onScrollEventHandler;
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // right mouse button => panning
            if( !event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
                return;

            sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
            sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

            sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX = canvas.getTranslateX();
            sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY = canvas.getTranslateY();

        }

    };

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // right mouse button => panning
            if( !event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
                return;

            canvas.setTranslateX(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX + event.getSceneX() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX);
            canvas.setTranslateY(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY + event.getSceneY() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY);

            event.consume();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Mouse wheel handler: zoom to pivot point
     */
    private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> onScrollEventHandler = new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {

            double delta = 1;

            double scale = canvas.getScale(); // currently we only use Y, same value is used for X
            double oldScale = scale;

            if (event.getDeltaY() < 0)
                scale -= delta;
            else
                scale += delta;

            if (scale <= MIN_SCALE) {
                scale = MIN_SCALE;
            } else if (scale >= MAX_SCALE) {
                scale = MAX_SCALE;
            }



            if (oldx==0){
             ttx=event.getSceneX() ;  
             tty=event.getSceneY() ;
            }else{
            if (oldx!=event.getSceneX()){
            ttx=((event.getSceneX()+oldx)/2) ;    
            }
            if (oldy!=event.getSceneY()){
            tty=((event.getSceneY()+oldy)/2);    
            }
            }
            // pivot value must be untransformed, i. e. without scaling
            canvas.setPivot( 
                    ((ttx- canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()) / oldScale),
                    ((tty- canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()) / oldScale)
                    );
         //    if (oldx==0){
            oldx=event.getSceneX();
            oldy=event.getSceneY();
         //   }
            //try {
             //   Robot rbt=new Robot();
             //   rbt.mouseMove(512, 384);
            //} catch (AWTException ex) {
            //    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
           // }

             canvas.setScale( scale);


            System.out.println( "new pivot x: " + canvas.scaleTransform.getPivotX() + "/" + canvas.scaleTransform.getPivotY() + ", new scale: " + scale);
            System.out.println( "bounds: " + canvas.getBoundsInParent());       
            System.out.println( "old: " + oldx+"  "+oldy);  
            System.out.println( "tt: " + ttx+"  "+tty);  
            event.consume();

        }

    };


}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when you zoom in to the circle, pan to the rectangle and continue zooming in. Jens-Peter's solution works. But I still want to thank you for your effort nontheless :-)

Answer (score 0):

In FX8 you can do

```
final Affine accumulatedScales = new Affine();  
chart.getTransforms().add(accumulatedScales);  

chart.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {  
    @Override public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {  
        accumulatedScales.appendScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, event.getX(), event.getY());  
    }  
});
```

and you are done

Comment: It doesn't work. When I e. g. have the mouse cursor over the center of the circle, the circle moves when I use the scroll wheel.

Answer (score 0):

With this approach you can zoom in position with transformed, rotated nodes.

```
    public static void zoom(Node node, double factor, ScrollEvent event) {

            double oldScale = node.getScaleX();
            double scale = oldScale*factor;
            if (scale < MIN_ZOOM) scale = MIN_ZOOM;
            if (scale > MAX_ZOOM)  scale = MAX_ZOOM;

            double x = event.getX();
            double y = event.getY();

            Point2D p0 = node.localToScene(x, y);

            node.setScaleX(scale);
            node.setScaleY(scale);

            Point2D p1 = node.localToScene(x, y);

            double deltaX = p1.getX() - p0.getX();
            double deltaY = p1.getY() - p0.getY();

            node.setTranslateX(node.getTranslateX() - deltaX);
            node.setTranslateY(node.getTranslateY() - deltaY);

        }
```