# JavaFx zooming to mouse as pivot

Tags: javafx, pivot, zooming

I have tried the this example given in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506156/javafx-8-zooming-relative-to-mouse-pointer) to learn about zooming and panning relative to the mouse pointer. When everything is on the grid, zooming works as expected:

*When zooming into the mouse pointer location on the top left image, it is zoomed into the exact location as seen in the top right image.*

If something is dragged off the grid, e.g. the pivot starts to 'misbehave':

*When zooming into the mouse pointer location on the bottom left image, it is zoomed into a location other than the one intended, seen in the bottom right image.*

The bounds of the canvas inside the parent changes from 600x600 (without scale) to something like 600x700… Which affects the outcomes dx, dy of the following function.

```
double dx = (event.getSceneX() - (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getWidth()/2 + canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()));
double dy = (event.getSceneY() - (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getHeight()/2 + canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()));
```

When editing this function by changing `.getWidth()` to `.getHeight()` and then again move the rectangle out **right**… the zoom works correctly. However, if the rectangle is moved out vertically (to the bottom or top) and to the left  the problem again is reproduced again.

Is the above function correct, what is it trying to do? Why does the zoom not work the same, as when everything was on the grid?

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

class PannableCanvas extends Pane {

    DoubleProperty myScale = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);

    public PannableCanvas() {
        setPrefSize(600, 600);
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey; -fx-border-color: blue;");

        // add scale transform
        scaleXProperty().bind(myScale);
        scaleYProperty().bind(myScale);
    }

    /**
     * Add a grid to the canvas, send it to back
     */
    public void addGrid() {

        double w = getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        double h = getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();

        // add grid
        Canvas grid = new Canvas(w, h);

        // don't catch mouse events
        grid.setMouseTransparent(true);

        GraphicsContext gc = grid.getGraphicsContext2D();

        gc.setStroke(Color.GRAY);
        gc.setLineWidth(1);

        // draw grid lines
        double offset = 50;
        for( double i=offset; i < w; i+=offset) {
            gc.strokeLine( i, 0, i, h);
            gc.strokeLine( 0, i, w, i);
        }

        getChildren().add( grid);

        grid.toBack();
    }

    public double getScale() {
        return myScale.get();
    }

    public void setScale( double scale) {
        myScale.set(scale);
    }

    public void setPivot( double x, double y) {
        setTranslateX(getTranslateX()-x);
        setTranslateY(getTranslateY()-y);
    }
}


/**
 * Mouse drag context used for scene and nodes.
 */
class DragContext {

    double mouseAnchorX;
    double mouseAnchorY;

    double translateAnchorX;
    double translateAnchorY;

}

/**
 * Listeners for making the nodes draggable via left mouse button. Considers if parent is zoomed.
 */
class NodeGestures {

    private DragContext nodeDragContext = new DragContext();

    PannableCanvas canvas;

    public NodeGestures( PannableCanvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;

    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
        return onMousePressedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
        return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // left mouse button => dragging
            if( !event.isPrimaryButtonDown())
                return;

            nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
            nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

            nodeDragContext.translateAnchorX = node.getTranslateX();
            nodeDragContext.translateAnchorY = node.getTranslateY();

        }

    };

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // left mouse button => dragging
            if( !event.isPrimaryButtonDown())
                return;

            double scale = canvas.getScale();

            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

            node.setTranslateX(nodeDragContext.translateAnchorX + (( event.getSceneX() - nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorX) / scale));
            node.setTranslateY(nodeDragContext.translateAnchorY + (( event.getSceneY() - nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorY) / scale));

            event.consume();

        }
    };
}

/**
 * Listeners for making the scene's canvas draggable and zoomable
 */
class SceneGestures {

    private static final double MAX_SCALE = 10.0d;
    private static final double MIN_SCALE = .1d;

    private DragContext sceneDragContext = new DragContext();

    PannableCanvas canvas;

    public SceneGestures( PannableCanvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
        return onMousePressedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
        return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<ScrollEvent> getOnScrollEventHandler() {
        return onScrollEventHandler;
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // right mouse button => panning
            if( !event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
                return;

            sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
            sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

            sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX = canvas.getTranslateX();
            sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY = canvas.getTranslateY();

        }

    };

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // right mouse button => panning
            if( !event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
                return;

            canvas.setTranslateX(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX + event.getSceneX() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX);
            canvas.setTranslateY(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY + event.getSceneY() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY);

            event.consume();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Mouse wheel handler: zoom to pivot point
     */
    private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> onScrollEventHandler = new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {

            double delta = 1.2;

            double scale = canvas.getScale(); // currently we only use Y, same value is used for X
            double oldScale = scale;

            if (event.getDeltaY() < 0)
                scale /= delta;
            else
                scale *= delta;

            scale = clamp( scale, MIN_SCALE, MAX_SCALE);

            double f = (scale / oldScale)-1;

            double dx = (event.getSceneX() - (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getWidth()/2 + canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()));
            double dy = (event.getSceneY() - (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getHeight()/2 + canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()));

            canvas.setScale( scale);

            // note: pivot value must be untransformed, i. e. without scaling
            canvas.setPivot(f*dx, f*dy);

            event.consume();

        }

    };


    public static double clamp( double value, double min, double max) {

        if( Double.compare(value, min) < 0)
            return min;

        if( Double.compare(value, max) > 0)
            return max;

        return value;
    }
}



/**
 * An application with a zoomable and pannable canvas.
 */
public class ZoomAndScrollApplication extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Group group = new Group();

        // create canvas
        PannableCanvas canvas = new PannableCanvas();

        // we don't want the canvas on the top/left in this example => just
        // translate it a bit
        canvas.setTranslateX(100);
        canvas.setTranslateY(100);

        // create sample nodes which can be dragged
        NodeGestures nodeGestures = new NodeGestures( canvas);

        Label label1 = new Label("Draggable node 1");
        label1.setTranslateX(10);
        label1.setTranslateY(10);
        label1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Label label2 = new Label("Draggable node 2");
        label2.setTranslateX(100);
        label2.setTranslateY(100);
        label2.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label2.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Label label3 = new Label("Draggable node 3");
        label3.setTranslateX(200);
        label3.setTranslateY(200);
        label3.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label3.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Circle circle1 = new Circle( 300, 300, 50);
        circle1.setStroke(Color.ORANGE);
        circle1.setFill(Color.ORANGE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        circle1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        circle1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100,100);
        rect1.setTranslateX(450);
        rect1.setTranslateY(450);
        rect1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        rect1.setFill(Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        rect1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        rect1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        canvas.getChildren().addAll(label1, label2, label3, circle1, rect1);

        group.getChildren().add(canvas);

        // create scene which can be dragged and zoomed
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 1024, 768);

        SceneGestures sceneGestures = new SceneGestures(canvas);
        scene.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, sceneGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        scene.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, sceneGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());
        scene.addEventFilter( ScrollEvent.ANY, sceneGestures.getOnScrollEventHandler());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        canvas.addGrid();

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the [scaling happens at the center of a node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#scaleXProperty). When you drag the rectangle outside, the parent's width changes and so does the scale.

Comment: Bit of a hack, but I created a new Pane with the same size as Canvas and added it to the constructor of Canvas. Then I replaced the bounds of Canvas in the function to that of the Pane… and then it works because this one does not resize. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

As nobody answered the question up until now and I stumbled over the same problem, I will post my solution, which adds a simple calculation of the left/up/lower and right overhang of nodes.

If you replace the part of the zooming-code with the part attached below, you should be good to got.

```
//maxX = right overhang, maxY = lower overhang
double maxX = canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX() - canvas.localToParent(canvas.getPrefWidth(), canvas.getPrefHeight()).getX();
double maxY = canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY() - canvas.localToParent(canvas.getPrefWidth(), canvas.getPrefHeight()).getY();

// minX = left overhang, minY = upper overhang
double minX = canvas.localToParent(0,0).getX() - canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX();
double minY = canvas.localToParent(0,0).getY() - canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY();

// adding the overhangs together, as we only consider the width of canvas itself
double subX = maxX + minX;
double subY = maxY + minY;

// subtracting the overall overhang from the width and only the left and upper overhang from the upper left point
double dx = (event.getSceneX() - ((canvas.getBoundsInParent().getWidth()-subX)/2 + (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()+minX)));
double dy = (event.getSceneY() - ((canvas.getBoundsInParent().getHeight()-subY)/2 + (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()+minY)));
```

WARNING: The left and up overhang will always be computed correctly, but I did not find any working way, to compute the right and lower overhang of nodes without the use of the preferred height and width attributes. So keep in mind, that you need these.

Also, you can improve the performance by only computing the canvas.getBoundsInParent() thing only once before as well as the the other calculations that are computed multiple times.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I click on a crossing, then zoom in. The cursor is still a little bit off, down and to the right. 15.0.1 on macOS 11.