# Zooming and panning image in scrollpane

Tags: javafx, zooming

I have a problem with zooming and panning image in ScrollPane. So far I have code like this:

```
Image image = imageView.getImage();
scrollPane.setPrefViewportWidth(0d);
scrollPane.setPrefViewportHeight(0d);
imageView.setFitWidth(0d);
imageView.setFitHeight(0d);
Bounds viewportBounds = scrollPane.getViewportBounds();
boolean vertical = image.getWidth() > image.getHeight();
if (imageView.getRotate() == 90 || imageView.getRotate() == 270d) {
  vertical = !vertical;
}

imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
double propX = viewportBounds.getWidth() / image.getWidth();
double propY = viewportBounds.getHeight() / image.getHeight();
boolean xLead = !(propX > propY);
imageView.setScaleX((xLead) ? propX : propY);
imageView.setScaleY((xLead) ? propX : propY);
scrollPane.setContent(imageView);

scrollPane.setPannable(true);

scrollPane.setHvalue(scrollPane.getHmin() + (scrollPane.getHmax() - scrollPane.getHmin()) / 2);     // center the scroll contents.
scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVmin() + (scrollPane.getVmax() - scrollPane.getVmin()) / 2);

zoom(imageView);

private void zoom(ImageView imagePannable) {
imagePannable.setOnScroll(
        new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
    double zoomFactor = 1.20;
    double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();

    if (deltaY < 0) {
      zoomFactor = 0.80;
    }
    imagePannable.setScaleX(imagePannable.getScaleX() * zoomFactor);
    imagePannable.setScaleY(imagePannable.getScaleY() * zoomFactor);
    event.consume();
  }
});
```

}

What I want to do is align image relative to mouse pointer not to center of image everytime. 
I also have a problem with large images (like maps which are 8*A4 size for example). When I zooming this maps pannable function stop working. What is wrong with this code? Thanks for helps!

Comment: Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 4):

Several people (including me) have had this same question. I got [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506156/javafx-8-zooming-relative-to-mouse-pointer).

In the interest of clarity, here is a working example of a panning & zooming pane using a rectangle as the zoomed node. I have implemented this in a slightly more complex way with an ImageView.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ZoomAndPanExample extends Application {

    private ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

    private final DoubleProperty zoomProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0d);
    private final DoubleProperty deltaY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0d);

    private final Group group = new Group();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        scrollPane.setPannable(true);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollPane, 10.0d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(scrollPane, 10.0d);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollPane, 10.0d);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scrollPane, 10.0d);

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(80, 60);

        rect.setStroke(Color.NAVY);
        rect.setFill(Color.NAVY);
        rect.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);

        group.getChildren().add(rect);
        // create canvas
        PanAndZoomPane panAndZoomPane = new PanAndZoomPane();
        zoomProperty.bind(panAndZoomPane.myScale);
        deltaY.bind(panAndZoomPane.deltaY);
        panAndZoomPane.getChildren().add(group);

        SceneGestures sceneGestures = new SceneGestures(panAndZoomPane);

        scrollPane.setContent(panAndZoomPane);
        panAndZoomPane.toBack();
        scrollPane.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, sceneGestures.getOnMouseClickedEventHandler());
        scrollPane.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, sceneGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        scrollPane.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, sceneGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());
        scrollPane.addEventFilter( ScrollEvent.ANY, sceneGestures.getOnScrollEventHandler());

        root.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class PanAndZoomPane extends Pane {

        public static final double DEFAULT_DELTA = 1.3d;
        DoubleProperty myScale = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
        public DoubleProperty deltaY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
        private Timeline timeline;


        public PanAndZoomPane() {

            this.timeline = new Timeline(60);

            // add scale transform
            scaleXProperty().bind(myScale);
            scaleYProperty().bind(myScale);
        }


        public double getScale() {
            return myScale.get();
        }

        public void setScale( double scale) {
            myScale.set(scale);
        }

        public void setPivot( double x, double y, double scale) {
            // note: pivot value must be untransformed, i. e. without scaling
            // timeline that scales and moves the node
            timeline.getKeyFrames().clear();
            timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(translateXProperty(), getTranslateX() - x)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(translateYProperty(), getTranslateY() - y)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(myScale, scale))
            );
            timeline.play();

        }

        public void fitWidth () {
            double scale = getParent().getLayoutBounds().getMaxX()/getLayoutBounds().getMaxX();
            double oldScale = getScale();

            double f = scale - oldScale;

            double dx = getTranslateX() - getBoundsInParent().getMinX() - getBoundsInParent().getWidth()/2;
            double dy = getTranslateY() - getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - getBoundsInParent().getHeight()/2;

            double newX = f*dx + getBoundsInParent().getMinX();
            double newY = f*dy + getBoundsInParent().getMinY();

            setPivot(newX, newY, scale);

        }

        public void resetZoom () {
            double scale = 1.0d;

            double x = getTranslateX();
            double y = getTranslateY();

            setPivot(x, y, scale);
        }

        public double getDeltaY() {
            return deltaY.get();
        }
        public void setDeltaY( double dY) {
            deltaY.set(dY);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Mouse drag context used for scene and nodes.
     */
    class DragContext {

        double mouseAnchorX;
        double mouseAnchorY;

        double translateAnchorX;
        double translateAnchorY;

    }

    /**
     * Listeners for making the scene's canvas draggable and zoomable
     */
    public class SceneGestures {

        private DragContext sceneDragContext = new DragContext();

        PanAndZoomPane panAndZoomPane;

        public SceneGestures( PanAndZoomPane canvas) {
            this.panAndZoomPane = canvas;
        }

        public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseClickedEventHandler() {
            return onMouseClickedEventHandler;
        }

        public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
            return onMousePressedEventHandler;
        }

        public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
            return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
        }

        public EventHandler<ScrollEvent> getOnScrollEventHandler() {
            return onScrollEventHandler;
        }

        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getX();
                sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getY();

                sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX = panAndZoomPane.getTranslateX();
                sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY = panAndZoomPane.getTranslateY();

            }

        };

        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                panAndZoomPane.setTranslateX(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX + event.getX() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX);
                panAndZoomPane.setTranslateY(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY + event.getY() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY);

                event.consume();
            }
        };

        /**
         * Mouse wheel handler: zoom to pivot point
         */
        private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> onScrollEventHandler = new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {

                double delta = PanAndZoomPane.DEFAULT_DELTA;

                double scale = panAndZoomPane.getScale(); // currently we only use Y, same value is used for X
                double oldScale = scale;

                panAndZoomPane.setDeltaY(event.getDeltaY()); 
                if (panAndZoomPane.deltaY.get() < 0) {
                    scale /= delta;
                } else {
                    scale *= delta;
                }

                double f = (scale / oldScale)-1;
                double dx = (event.getX() - (panAndZoomPane.getBoundsInParent().getWidth()/2 + panAndZoomPane.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()));
                double dy = (event.getY() - (panAndZoomPane.getBoundsInParent().getHeight()/2 + panAndZoomPane.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()));

                panAndZoomPane.setPivot(f*dx, f*dy, scale);

                event.consume();

            }
        };

        /**
         * Mouse click handler
         */
        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseClickedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                    if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        panAndZoomPane.resetZoom();
                    }
                }
                if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
                    if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        panAndZoomPane.fitWidth();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```