# How can i drag and drop JavaFX shapes on a pane with my mouse?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm writing a little program where you can create different (JavaFX) shapes like rectangles, circles, ellipses, lines and polygons. After starting the program or creating a shape, the saved shapes (they are saved in a file system) are being added to a pane with the following line of code:

```java
pane.getChildren().add(rectangle1)
```

My question is: What is a good approach to be able to drag these shapes around on the pane and also be able to adjust their properties? I am using the SceneBuilder.

I am relative new to programming, especially to JavaFX and SceneBuilder so I'm really not sure about the approach here and if I should change the way I project the shape objects in the first place.

Thanks to anyone helping me out!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29530135/230513).

Comment: https://jenkov.com/tutorials/javafx/drag-and-drop.html

Comment: See: [sample app for dragging around text boxes and adjusting their properties](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2724651), doing the same for shapes can be similar.